# Entries retrieved from table are being duplicated? PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a page of results on my site, im using AJAX to return more reslts when scrolled down, my problem is however as it pulls the results, it seems to pull the same ones multiple times? I dont know what causes this, can anybody see what im doing wrong?

**AJAX**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10)  {
         var number = $(".directory").children().length;
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "getentries.php",
           data: "count="+number,
           success: function(results){
             $('.directory').append(results);
           }
         });



    } else {}
});
```

**PHP**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM directory LIMIT {$_POST['count']},12");

$c = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<div class="entry';
            if (($c % 4) == 1) echo ' alpha ';
            echo 'ALL THE DATA IS GOING HERE';      
            $c++;
  }
```

Comment: What does firebug (or whatever debugger) say? Does the js call the php twice eventually?

Comment: change $('.directory').append(results); to $('.directory').html(results); and see if you get just the data you want appended

Comment: No luck @WebweaverD, same thing occurs

Comment: Does `{$_POST['count']}` yield the expected number?

Comment: Do you close your `<div>` tag in the PHP??

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your offset number. Is the post sending the correct count?

Comment: I do close it MrCode, and yes @MatthewNie the count's correct...

Comment: Rereading your question are you getting the results you want but your ending up with multiples of the results? If so it has to do with the scroll event, it gets called on every single movement of the bar so it could call the ajax function 5 times even though you moved a tiny ammount.

Comment: Try building the SQL string without curly braces, `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM directory LIMIT " . $_POST['count'] . ",12");`.

Comment: That doesn't retrieve any data now @Beetroot-Beetroot

Comment: Inspect the SQL - is it correct?

Comment: I think thats my problem @MatthewNie, if I scroll fast up and down I get strange results and sometimes my browser crashes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely multiple ajax calls being fired while you scroll. Set up a timed event listener like so:

```
didScroll = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        if(($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
            // load more results
        }
    }
}, 250);
```

This article explains why your solution is a bad idea: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: I would be happier with a solution that also takes ajaxInProgress into account as per @MathewNie, or similar. You should at least abort any ajax that is currently in progress before requesting anew.

Comment: I agree with @Beetroot-Beetroot, making sure you don't still have an ajax call in progress would add to the robustness.

Comment: Possible consequence of not doing so - *duplicate results* - back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that you are making the ajax call multiple times once you hit your scroll threshold. You need to add a flag on the first ajax call so it doens't get called again until the ajax call has finished.

```
ajaxInProgress = false;
if (!ajaxInProgress && ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10)) {
    ajaxInProgress = true;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getentries.php",
       data: "count="+number,
       success: function(results){
         ajaxInProgress = false;
         $('.directory').append(results);
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MatthewNie, its still duplicating my results however :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you are passing data with your ajax call. From the Jquery docs, you need to put count and the amount in a javascript object within data:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getentries.php",
       data: {count: number},
       success: function(results){
         $('.directory').append(results);
       }
     });
```

Once you fix this, your Mysql query should return the correct next pieces of data to your view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: data: " It is converted to a query string, if not already a string."

Comment: You can send as a sting or an object. FYI